# How to process while waiting for user input from ContentDialog

Tags: c#, async-await, uwp

With asynchronous tasks I often postpone `await` to perform other processing while waiting for async task to return. For example, instead of:

```
bool t = await myAsync();
```

I use

```
Task<bool> t = myAsync();
//do something else here while waiting
await t; //or await Task.WhenAll(t, p, s); when more than one
```

How can I use this approach with `ContentDialog`? I want to display content dialog to the user and perform other processing while the user waits to respond.

I tried below approach but that fails because `ContentDialog` returns `IAsyncOperation` instead of a `Task`.

```
Task<ContentDialogResult> result = myContentDialog.ShowAsync();
//do something else here
await result;
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What happens if you write `var result = myContentDialog.ShowAsync();` instead?

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped me figure it out!

Comment: How about the progress? If the issue has been solved, please mark the useful answer. For that, more members that facing the same question could get help quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IAsyncOperation` works similar to `Task`.
I was able to achieve this by awaiting `IAsyncOperation` and then using `GetResults()` to get the user response.

To replicate create a `Button` and `TextBox` named "MyTextBox" then paste below code in `Button_Clicked` event.

```
//prep dialog
ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog
{
     Content = "Test Dialog",
     Title = "Test Dialog",
     SecondaryButtonText = "Cancel",
     PrimaryButtonText = "OK"
};


//show dialog
IAsyncOperation<ContentDialogResult> result = dialog.ShowAsync();

//do some background processing
MyTextBlock.Text = "background processing...";

//wait for user response
_ = await result;

//get user response
ContentDialogResult buttonClicked = result.GetResults();
            
//display user response on screen
if(buttonClicked != ContentDialogResult.Primary)
{
    MyTextBlock.Text += "\nYou cancelled!";
}
else
{
   MyTextBlock.Text += "\nYou pressed OK!";
}
```